# Make columns non-hideable in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, configuration, datagrid, jqgrid

I would like to make some columns non-hideable and perhaps immovable. I've seen arguable solutions on trirand.com and SO to making a column immovable under horizontal scrolling (e.g. http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/Lock%20Columns/), but I haven't seen a solution to also make a column non-hideable.

Is there a way to let people hide and show columns, but not certain specific columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the property [hidedlg:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) in the colModel can solve the problem?

Comment: Right, this looks like exactly what he is asking for: `If set to true this column will not appear in the modal dialog where users can choose which columns to show or hide.`